# TypeError at /admin/attempt/add_model/add/

Tags: django

## my models

class add_category(models.Model):

```
addcategory=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.addcategory
```

class sub_category(models.Model):

```
category=models.ForeignKey('add_category',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='xyz')

subcategory=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subcategory
```

class add_texture_categ(models.Model):

```
addtexturecategory=models.CharField(max_length=20)


def __str__(self):
    return self.addtexturecategory
```

class add_texture(models.Model):

```
apply_texture=models.ForeignKey('add_texture_categ',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
texture_name=models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
texture_image=models.FileField(blank=True, default="", upload_to="media/images")

def __str__(self):
    return self.texture_name
```

class add_model(models.Model):

```
select_category=models.ForeignKey('add_category',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

select_sub_category=models.ForeignKey('sub_category',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

available_in=models.ForeignKey('add_texture_categ',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

model_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
length=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
breadth=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
base=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

name=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

image = models.FileField(blank=True, default=""
,upload_to="media/images")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

## my viewset

class add_modelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

```
def create(self,request):
    try:
        data=request.data
        model_name=data.get('model_name')
        length=data.get('length')
        breadth=data.get('breadth')
        base=data.get('base')
        select_category=data.get('select_category')
        select_sub_category=data.get('select_sub_category')
        available_in=data.get('available_in')
        new=add_model()
        new.model_name=model_name
        new.length=length
        new.breadth=breadth
        new.base=base
        new.select_category=add_category.objects.get(addcategory=select_category)
        new.select_sub_category=sub_category.objects.get(subcategory=select_sub_category)
        new.available_in=add_texture_categ.objects.get(addtexturecategory=available_in)
        new.save()   
        return Response({'submit':True})
    except Exception as error:
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False},
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## why am i getting this **str** returned non string type

Comment: And what's in your admin file for this models?

Comment: admin.site.register(add_model)

Comment: did you properly run all migrations? Seems like your problem is in `__str__` method for `add_model`. Try to remove it and see if you can now enter the admin.

Comment: i deleted my database ,migrations then migrate error solved,i want to know why this is happening again and again.